# How to cast list of text items from jsonb field to perform IN clause by field of type uuid?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

There is `foo` table with following fields:

- ***uuid*** of type uuid
- ***info*** of type jsonb

Among of other things `info` field contains `bar` key with list of uuids from the same table(`foo`). Now I need to select all `foo` entries where uuid in list of info->'bar' for some particular entry. I tried select query below and got `operator does not exist: uuid = uuid[]` error

```sql
SELECT uuid 
FROM foo 
WHERE uuid IN (SELECT jsonb_array_to_text_array(info->'bar')::uuid[] 
               FROM foo 
               WHERE uuid='some_uuid');
```

How I need to modify the query to do this? I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [no such function named `jsonb_array_to_text_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

But you can use the `jsonb_array_elements_text()` function, which expands every array element into one row. With this result you are able to filter by them to find the uuids.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cf02db52eef7504dbae2ac6f90221058)

```
SELECT
    elements::int AS uuid
FROM
    foo,
    jsonb_array_elements_text(info -> 'bar') elements
WHERE uuid = 4
```

---

If you want the whole record:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=89dee07922f0ea627252fa379cc62668)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM foo
WHERE uuid IN (
    SELECT
        elements::int
    FROM
        foo,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(info -> 'bar') elements
    WHERE uuid = 4  
)
```

Comment: ahh, sorry I forgot to mention that jsonb_array_elements_text is my custom function based on jsonb_array_elements_text function. Just checked your solution and yes, it's worked. Thank you